# Custom media type Consume rest call post operation

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jax-rs, spring-rest

Need to consume rest service which as below. jersy client

```
@POST
@Produces("application/vnd.app.mail-service+json")
@Consumes("application/vnd.app.mail-service+json")
public TempResponse submit(TempRequest request) {

}
```

Here the TempRequest is JAXB object.

To consume the service from javascript. have set the Accept and Content-Type as "application/vnd.app.mail-service+json" and sending the json request

```
{
  "TempRequest" :{
       "TempR1" : {
          "id" : "1212",
          "name" : "app",
        }
  }
}
```

On submitting request, the received request body in the Service application is empty, if i try with "+xml" in both consumes and produces and change content type the request body is not empty.

Using Jersy-cleint and jax-rs with deployed in spring 4.3.7 application with jacson-core and asl - 1.19.3

Comment: what is `TempRequest ` ? is it your custom class ?

Comment: it is custom class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you using `application/vnd.app.mail-service+json` instead of `application/json`.

Same needs to be changed to

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

And I hope, you have similar changes in `TempRequest` class, which is a JAXB class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TempRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TempRequest {

    @XmlElement(name="TempR1") 
    private TempR1 temp;

    public TempRequest() {}

    // Getter and setter methods
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Already the service is up and running and will need to consume the service which is of custom media type.Should i still need to create the jaxb object in the consuming part to make it work

Comment: jersey will take of instantiation of custom object.